# WordPress Infinite link problem? How can I fix this?

Tags: wordpress

WordPress has endless link problems for many years. Note: This problem happens when we paged comment example:

https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-properly-ask-for-wordpress-support-and-get-it/comment-page-2754/

https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-properly-ask-for-wordpress-support-and-get-it/comment-page-5754/

Attention! There are no comments on these pages. But the links are entering the article. If there is no comment, that link should not work.

This problem happens in **paginations.**.

If the setting is like this. screen shot: https://prnt.sc/smhi90

How can I fix this? Maybe, How can I redirect these bad links to 404 page? thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't break your site and take you to the post, I don't think it is a problem. Redirecting to a 404 page is bad user experience as it direct the user from the article

Comment: These are bad links. Links that shouldn't be.

Comment: We'll agree to disagree on this. I do not think it's a bad link